# How do I get such a nested lists?

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

```
variable tree structure

- nestedList1 variable

aa3
 |
aa1      aa2      bb1
   \    /        /
     aa       bb
       \     /
         root

- nestedList2 variable

              bb4
               |
aa3           bb2     bb3
 |              \     /
aa1      aa2      bb1    cc1
   \    /        /        |
     aa       bb         cc
       \       |        /
              root
```

```
nestedList1 = ['root', ['aa', ['aa1', ['aa3'], 'aa2'], 'bb', ['bb1']]]
nestedList2 = ['root', ['aa', ['aa1', ['aa3'], 'aa2'], 'bb', ['bb1', ['bb2', ['bb4'], 'bb3']], 'cc', ['cc1']]]

def ConvertTraverse(nlist, depth=0):
    convertlist = []
    for leaf in nlist:
        if isinstance(leaf, list):
            tmplist = ConvertTraverse(leaf, depth+1)
            convertlist.insert(0, tmplist)
        else:
            convertlist += [leaf]
    return convertlist

print ConvertTraverse(nestedList1)
print ConvertTraverse(nestedList2)
```

- result
  nestedList1: `[[['bb1'], [['aa3'], 'aa1', 'aa2'], 'aa', 'bb'], 'root']`
  nestedList2: `[[['cc1'], [[['bb4'], 'bb2', 'bb3'], 'bb1'], [['aa3'], 'aa1', 'aa2'], 'aa', 'bb', 'cc'], 'root']`

All I want is the results below.

- result
  nestedList1: `[[[['aa3'], 'aa1', 'aa2'], 'aa', ['bb1'], 'bb'], 'root']`
  nestedList2: `[[[['aa3'], 'aa1', 'aa2'], 'aa', [[['bb4'], 'bb2', 'bb3'], 'bb1'], 'bb', ['cc1'], 'cc'], 'root']`

How do I get such a nested list?
I want a nested list, ordered to post-order traverse.

Comment: Maybe it will be better if each branch will be encaplsulated in parenthesis  i.e. `nestedList1 = ['root', ['aa', ['aa1', ['aa3']], ['aa2']], ['bb', ['bb1']]]` Then you can recursively move the first item to the end. However, if you want to make sure with the deepest cutting branch some more manipulation is needed.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do in order to reorder the list: Whenever the `n`th element is a label, and the `n+1`th element is a sublist, swap the two. You can do this *in-place* in a few line:

```
def reorder(lst):
    for i, (cur, nxt) in enumerate(zip(lst, lst[1:])):
        if isinstance(cur, str) and isinstance(nxt, list):
            reorder(nxt)
            lst[i:i+2] = [nxt, cur]
```

For a *not-in-place* solution, you can just create a deep-copy of the list and then use that on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I may be out of line here, or completely missing the point, but I'll risk claiming that I think it will be easier if you collect each branch fully to parenthesis. i.e. write each branch as an distinctive [root, [branch1], [branch2],...]

```
nestedList1 = ['root', ['aa', ['aa1', ['aa3']], ['aa2']], ['bb', ['bb1']]]
nestedList2 = ['root', ['aa', ['aa1', ['aa3']], ['aa2']], ['bb', ['bb1', ['bb2', ['bb4']], ['bb3']]], ['cc', ['cc1']]]
```

Then you can just recursively change the order to make each branch leaves-1st, trunk-2nd.

```
def recursivereverese(l):
    if len(l)<=1 or type(l) is not list:
        return l
    else:
        new = []
        for k in l[::-1]:
            new.append(recursivereverese(k))
        return new
```

The results on the modified nestedlists:

```
In [127]: recursivereverese(nestedList1)
Out[127]: [[['bb1'], 'bb'], [['aa2'], [['aa3'], 'aa1'], 'aa'], 'root']

In [128]: recursivereverese(nestedList2)
Out[128]: 
[[['cc1'], 'cc'],
 [[['bb3'], [['bb4'], 'bb2'], 'bb1'], 'bb'],
 [['aa2'], [['aa3'], 'aa1'], 'aa'],
 'root']
```

Is this what you were after?

Finding which branch are deeper for nice plotting is a different topic.